# Redirect on certain URLs

Tags: windows

Hi I have a problem where I'm setting up an internet Kiosk in a public place and when a user goes to a certain URL I want it to redirect to another particular URL.

For example I want it setup so that if a user goes to www.example.com/step1 I want the browser to automatically go to www.example.com/step2

The only restriction here is that it has to work on Windows due to hardware limitations.

Does anybody know how I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will go with the Browser Helper Object.

I also found this FireFox addon - Redirector - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5064 -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of ways to do it:

- Implement a [Browser Helper Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object), catch the `BeforeNavigate` event, cancel the navigation and direct it somewhere else.
- Use a specialized proxy server that responds to a request for the first URL by returning a redirect to the second, and passes all other requests through.

Comment: That is a top notch answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could try to modify the Hosts file. In Windows, I think it is found in WINDOWS/system32/drivers/.

It can be used to redirect a request for one IP address to another.
Hope that's useful.